# how to parse a custom column in excel file using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to parse a excel file which has a date time(mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss) stored in custom format. When I check the cell type it is indicating a numeric value, but I am not able to retrieve the value. It is displaying the below exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.typeMismatch(HSSFCell.java:648)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(HSSFCell.java:673)
```

When i try to read the value as date using 'cell.getDateCellValue()', then also I am  getting the same exception.

If I try to retrieve the value as a string, then the exception is just reversed.

Any idea how to make this work ?

Comment: Are you sure it's really a date cell? The exception makes it sound like rather than typing in the date + formatting it, someone just wrote it as a string. (Difference between `01/01/2010` and `'01/01/2010` - note the `'` at the start of the second)

Comment: May be I am not clear. The information the cell holds is date time but the cell type is custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having similar issues with apache poi.

My suggestion would be to:

1) force the cell to be text `cell.setCellType(CELLTYPESTRING)`

2) read in the string value `cell.getStringCellValue()`

3) do something on your end to parse the string into meaningful data

Hope this helps.  Apache POI has its limitations so sometimes you have to hack it like that

Comment: Did you look at the [Apache POI javadocs for Cell.setCellType(String)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29)? Only they're pretty clear on that not being a sensible option in quite a lot of cases...

Comment: I am not sure if what @Ben suggested is correct, but it worked for me. But after parsing the data I need to do some weird data manipulations to convert the parsed information into useful data. Neither less it worked !